# Cygnus Subscription to Orion

Tags: mongodb, fiware, fiware-orion, fiware-cygnus

Have a real LWM2M device working. Now I pulled Cygnus image to subscribe for historic context from MongoDB. 
From MongoDB, the following databases have been created:

```
mongo
>show dbs
admin              0.000GB
local              0.000GB
lwm2miotagent      0.000GB
orion              0.000GB
orion-smartgondor  0.000GB
```

But no historic database has been created, meaning Cygnus is not subscribing to Orion, I can see I tested that Cygnus is working.

What needs to be done (configuration or else) to have Cygnus subscribe to Orion? Using docker-compose to start/stop services.

Answer (score 1):

How to connect Orion to Cygnus (basically, how to create the required subscription) is explained in [this section of the Cygnus documentation](https://fiware-cygnus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cygnus-ngsi/user_and_programmer_guide/connecting_orion/index.html).

You can check existing subscriptions at Context Broker using the following request on the Orion Context Broker API endpoint, described in the [NGSIv2 specification](http://telefonicaid.github.io/fiware-orion/api/v2/stable/):

```
GET /v2/subscriptions
```

This is a way of checking if the Cygnus subscription has been correctly created.

(You have to use the `fiware-service` and `fiware-servicepath` HTTP headers in the above request to get the subscriptions of your particular service and subservice).

Comment: Yes, I tried Orion-Cygnus subscriptions from the link you shared above. It worked for emulated devices but not with real device, I only see the entities in MongoDB but not historic context observed.

Just reading further from https://fiware-cygnus.readthedocs.io/en/1.2.0/cygnus-common/installation_and_administration_guide/cygnus_agent_conf/index.html It appears I need some configuration files: cygnus_instance_<id>.conf and agent_<id>.conf
Hope I am not missing the points.

Comment: Executing GET /v2/subscriptions as suggested above returns empty list [ ].

Does that mean even the lightweightm2m-iotagent isn't subscribed to Orion? I ask this because I can see client info in collections within orion-smartgondor database above, collections within lwm2miotagent database is also empty. What a confusion!

Comment: Hi @fgalan I edited  cygnus_instance_1.conf and  agent_1.conf as according to https://fiware-cygnus.readthedocs.io/en/0.13.0/installation_and_administration_guide/cygnus_agent_conf/index.html but it seems cygnus is starting up with the default cygnus_instance.conf and agent.conf files. How can I chage it work with my settings?

Comment: "Executing GET /v2/subscriptions as suggested above returns empty list [ ]. Does that mean even the lightweightm2m-iotagent isn't subscribed to Orion?" IOTAs doesn't use subscription in its main operational flow. More detail on this at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fiware-orion

Comment: "What a confusion!" It is not so confusing if you know the purpose of each database ;). lwm2miotagent is used by the IOTA (provisioned devices and configurations, mainly), orion is used by CB for the default service (i.e. the one you get if you omit `fiware-service` header), orion-smartgondor is used by CB for the `fiware-service: smartgondor` service. None of these DBs seems to be related with Cygnus.

Comment: By the way, you seem to be using a mix of URLs for Cygnus documentation (1.2.0, 0.13.0...). It would be clever to stick to the one you actually has. If x.y.z is your Cygnus version, then use documentation always under https://fiware-cygnus.readthedocs.io/en/x.y.z/

Comment: note taken. So what could be wrong with my Cygnus configuration that I am unable to get historic data? I understand Cygnus needs to create the db (mongodb) to store historic context.

Comment: MongoDB are usually created on the fly. I mean, first time you insert a document in a collection of the database, it is created. Maybe Cygnus creates the database the first time it receives a notification from Orion and has to persist it.